# Loop through each visible worksheet and clear data found by filtering on a column

Tags: vba, excel, loops

My code is not looping through each worksheet which is not hidden. The desired result is for the code to loop through each worksheet which is visible and clear previous data found by filtering on column A with the variable `ProjectN`:

```
  Workbooks(pics).Activate
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In Workbooks(pics).Worksheets
  If ws.Visible = True Then
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    Cells.AutoFilter
    End If
    Cells.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ProjectN
        If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count >= 1 Then
        Range("A2:A100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
            If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
            Cells.AutoFilter
            End If
  End If
  Next ws
```

Can anyone could let me know why this is not working?

Comment: Hi Sean, is it looping through ALL worksheets then?

Comment: What does "not working" mean, exactly? If you strip everything inside the outer `If` statement, and replaced with a simple `Debug.Print` statement, would it loop through the worksheets for you?

Comment: When I debug it (using F5) it does not go through the relevant worksheets

Comment: Does it not loop at all, or does it skip some?

Comment: It does not loop at all, apologies I should have been clearer in my orginal post

Comment: stick a `ws.Activate` statement after the `If ws.Visible = True` I suspect that it is looping, but it's not actually doing the filtering because you are always working with whatever sheet was active when you ran the code. I will post as answer as well.

Comment: Scott makes a good point. You are using `ActiveSheet.FilterMode`. It would be preferable to either activate the sheet, or use `ws.FilterMode`. I prefer the latter method. Refer to the sheet explicitly, don't assume it is active.

Comment: Thanks all, this has resolved it! Knew it was something simple! Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: If it is resolved, please mark an answer below, so other users can benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I said in my comment that you can activate the sheet, but you can do without that and just refer directly to the sheet. Either way, you need to tell VBA explicitly which sheet to work with. It will not automatically activate each sheet when looping through the worksheets.

See my code below:

EDIT: I also changed the range in your `.EntireRow.Delete` statement. If you have a lot of empty rows down the sheet, there is no need to waste resources (time) and delete those. The changes I made will make execution faster.

```
Workbooks(pics).Activate

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Workbooks(pics).Worksheets

    With ws

        If .Visible Then

            If .FilterMode Then .Cells.AutoFilter

            .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ProjectN

            If .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count >= 1 Then
                .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A100000").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

            If .FilterMode Then .Cells.AutoFilter

        End If

    End With

Next ws
```

Comment: is is mandatory to activate the wb and state its name in for each? (If my code acts on the same wb.)

Comment: @PatatesPilées - not mandatory, but always best practice to explicitly state the object you want to work with. `ThisWorbook` may be a better way for you.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't loop because you only work with the ActiveSheet inside the loop

- You should activate `ws` each time through the loop (bad practice)
- Or qualify all references to use the `ws` variable - see (untested) code bellow

---

```
Workbooks(pics).Activate
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Workbooks(pics).Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Visible Then
            If .FilterMode Then .Cells.AutoFilter
            .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ProjectN
            With .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                If .Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
            .Cells.AutoFilter
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Comment: you must have been writing your answer when I posted mine, because they are almost *identical*! One issue that I noticed in your answer is that the `.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete` will delete the probable header row (row 1) of the sheet. I surmise this because the user wanted to delete only from row 2 on.